# insert record using mysqli with one page

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm wondering what's the problem with this code? 
What I want to happen is to insert record when I click the Submit Button. But it seems I'm having a problem with the isset function.

```
 Database Name: dbase

 Table Name: tblmessage

 Fields:
 message_id - INT - auto increment
 message - TEXT
```

Update:
I can't still add / insert record in my database.

Thank you in advance!

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Message: <input type = "text" name = "message">
    </br></br>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","dbase");

        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = ""INSERT INTO tblmessage (message_id, message) VALUES (NULL, '$message')";
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

          if ($insert) {
              echo "Message successfully added!";
          }
          else {
            echo "Error" . mysqli_error($conn);
          }
      }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow that is really risky. You directly query the content of an input field to your database. This screams SQL-injection. What exactly is the content of your meesage-input? a real query like `INSERT INTO...` or just a text and you want to save that in your database?

Comment: @wayneOS I already added the sql - insert.. but still not working :(

Comment: if you want help, provide an accurate description of your problem. "not working" is inadequate.

Comment: @wayneOS is right. You want to use something like prepared statements and parametized queries to avoid mysql injections before you query your input. As for the current problem, is 'message' your table name? What error mesage are you receiving?

Comment: To check the error you are receiving, do something like this `<?php

// From http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

$sql = "INSERT INTO (message) VALUES ('$message')";
if (!$sql) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: @MosesKirathe I already added the name of the table, but it still doesn't add a record in my database. Thanks!

Comment: Echo this out after the insert attempt and paste it into your question  `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: And please, please, please, heed the advice of @wayneOS, you're code is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: @TarekAdam I already added: mysqli_error($conn); but it doesn't show any error. Yes I understand wayneOS advice, I'm only wondering why this part of my code is not working. Thank you!

Comment: you can omit `action` on your form if you're just gonna submit it on the same page.

Comment: @CodeSurfer Change this `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $pass,$db);` with the code found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp). Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) on how to turn on the PHP errors.

Comment: @hungrykoala I did your suggestion, problem is "Message successfully added!" is appearing even I haven't hit the submit button.

Comment: Why are you doing `implode(',',$message)` when inserting a message? that's only applicable for arrays and your $message is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Code just copy and paste it

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Message: <input type = "text" name = "message">
    </br></br>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbase");
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblmessage (message_id, message) VALUES (NULL, '" . $message . "')";
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        if ($insert) {
            echo "Message successfully added!";
        } else {
            echo "Error" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already did your suggestion/advice, still I can't add/insert a record.

Comment: I didn't see any error output... I just can't add record when I hit the submit button and check phymyadmin to see if it succeeded, but unfortunately it didn't add.

Comment: Thank you! Problem Solved! :)

Comment: @PavanSikarwar why did you try to edit my answer into a wrong answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to implode a String. Read about [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Change:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tblmessage (message) VALUES (NULL, ".implode(',',$message).")";
  $insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

To:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tblmessage (message_id, message) VALUES (NULL, '$message')";
  $insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: I just did Pavan Sikarwar suggestion, I'll do your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You don´t have any `SQL-Statement` in your Code. 
If you want to insert the Message from your form you need to change `$sql`.

```
$sql = INSERT into dbase(your_database_field) Values ($message);
$sql-statement=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

You should sanitize your input before sending your data to the database.

Comment: I already added:

    $sql = "INSERT INTO (message) VALUES ('$message')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

but still not working :(